# Snackbar hiding FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have two activities BaseActivity(Parent Layout is `CoordinatorLayout`) and SecondActivity. In SecondActivity there is one fragment which contain `FloatingActionButton`.

In `BaseActivity` I am displaying an `Snackbar`. That `Snackbar` is overlapping with `FloatingActionButton`.

How can i move this button up when i'll display snackbar.

Comment: Use coordinator layout

Answer (score 1):

Without relevant code, it is impossible to give a correct answer. However your issue usually gets resolved when `CoordinatorLayout` is used as parent for FAB. Example code would be something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_snackbar"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/black" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If the above code doesn't resolve your issue, add the relevant code as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

use in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.pawanl.demo.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in mainactivity-

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```